# How to get parameters for a script?

Tags: c#, powershell

I have the below function to run a PowerShell script. I am trying to get information on what parameters are needed for the script by calling `Get-Help <scriptPath>`.

In PowerShell application I see `test2.ps1 [[-Name] <String>] [[-Age] <Int32>] [[-Path] <String>]`, which is perfect, but I cant seem to find this information in C#.

After running the script I get a single `PSObject` and the string builder returns blank.

Can someone point me in the right direction to what I am missing?

```cs
private string RunScript(string scriptText)
{
    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

    runspace.Open();

    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);

    pipeline.Commands.Add("Out-String");

    Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();

    runspace.Close();

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (PSObject obj in results)
    {
        stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
    }

    return stringBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Worked just fine for me when I passed in the string `"Get-Help C:\\path\\to\\script.ps1"`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers what kind of output did you get? Like I mentioned I dont get errors, i just cant seem to find the data im looking for

Comment: The same output I got from running `Get-Help C:\path\to\script.ps1` in a PowerShell console: `script.ps1 [[-Name] <string>] [[-Age] <int>] [[-Path] <string>] [<CommonParameters>]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was using `@"Get-Help C:\Path\To\Stuff"` which resulted in a blank response.

Changing it to `"Get-Help C:\\Path\\To\\Stuff"` fixed this issue.

Comment: Curious. According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) either string literal should have worked.